# Next multiple integer of a float number

Tags: terminology

Is there any way to get the next integer multiple of a given float number? An if so, how is it called?
Let's say, if you have $1.5$, the next one will be $3 \,(= 1.5 \cdot 2 )$ , but when it's not that easy to guess, it can take some time without any formula.

Comment: Sounds like you're just referring to the numerator of a given rational number?  If so then you will want to specify a tolerance for whether $1.49999$ should be treated the same as $1.5$.  Then look up "continued fractions".

Comment: If you're working with *exact* fractions, this is the numerator in the reduced fraction.